# How to run a script as a File in Java?

Tags: java, python, maven

I have a Python script which is a resource in my project. Along with the script is an XML file that the script needs in order to run properly. I am reading in both files as an InputStream and then creating temp files for both:

```
InputStream is = (this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("InterWebApp.py"));
File script = File.createTempFile("script", ".py");
Files.copy(is, script.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
InputStream is1 = (this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("setup.xml"));
File xml  = File.createTempFile("config", ".xml");
Files.copy(is1, xml.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

However, I am not sure how to launch the script as a process:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("." + script.getAbsolutePath());
p.waitFor();
```

The above code throws an IOException. How do I run `script.py` and ensure it has access to `config.xml`? Right now the Python script just parses the XML file using the absolute path, but this path would not be the same for the temp file.

Comment: I'm very rusty on Java and know little of the `File` class, but this looks suspect to me: `"." + script.getAbsolutePath()`.  Seems you'd want `"./"` or `".\"` depending on your environment, and you'd want the basic file name, not the absolute path.

Comment: @JuanTomas I tried `"./" + script.getName()` but an exception was thrown because the process couldn't find the file

Comment: Could you please provide the exception ?

Comment: Propably you have a reason but why don't you use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're asking yourself for trouble since you ask it for the absolute path, but then prefix it with ".", which is generally a *relative path* modifier. Try `.exec(script.getAbsolutePath())` for starters. Also, depending on your operating system and/or configuration, `.py` files might or might not be recognized as executable (for example, on Unix systems only files with an executable flag will be recognized as executable). You might actually want to find the location of the Python executable and pass the script as a parameter.

Comment: I am running Linux and when I try your suggestion for the `.getAbsolutePath`, I get a permission denied error. Is there a workaround for this issue? I've been told executing the actual resource file packaged in the JAR is basically impossible.

Comment: You'll have to set file permissions between writing the file and trying to execute it.

Comment: I set the permission to executed using `.exec("chmod 777 " + script.getAbsolutePath())` but I get a permission denied exception the first time the method is called, but the second time it starts the process successfully but the service does not run

Comment: If you get a permission denied, that probably means your code execution stops there because of the exception. Try setting the executable flag from outside the Java process, it might run with weakened permissions (i.e. _nobody_)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and resolved the issue. However, the script still does not run (I'm just opening a browser and hitting the localhost to see if it is actively running). With this, I think the issue is that it cannot find the xml file

Comment: You can do xml.getAbsolutePath() as well (for the temp file).